# changes made by one thread to shared data are visible to other threads not use volatile

Tags: jvm, volatile

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadTest{
     boolean runStatus = true;
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("test run!!!");
        while (runStatus){
        }
        System.out.println("test end!!!");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
        new Thread(threadTest::test,"t1").start();

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        threadTest.runStatus = false;
    }
}
```

the code run in this jvm:

> java version "1.8.0_65" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_65-b17) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

like volatile used in **runStatus** variable，the while is stop.
but in this jvm, while is run all:

> java version "1.8.0_181" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
> 1.8.0_181-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

it is confusing,why is it exist this phenomenon?

Comment: The absence of `volatile` does not guaranty invisibility of updates, it guarantees nothing. That’s what every documentation and article says about it, the other thread may or may not perceive the update.

Comment: In technical terms, you have a data race between the write and read of the runStatus. The consequence is that weird things can happen like a compiler optimizing out the load/store.

Answer (score 1):

The newer JVM performed an allowed optimization and converted the while loop to an unchecked infinite loop. The older JVM is a "Client VM", and it generally performs fewer optimizations. The Client VM read the field each time even though it wasn't declared volatile, simply because it was "easier" to compile the code this way.

When the field isn't declared volatile or accessed using a lock or synchronized, the JVM is free to assume that no other threads will ever change the field value. It's allowed to re-write the loop as `while (true) { }`.

There was a lengthy thread a few months ago on the Java concurrency mailing list, discussing the same problem you're experiencing with respect to infinite loops. The simple answer is that because the JVM can perform a memory access optimization, always assume that it will.